# How to redirect output by a diffrent process initiated by java

Tags: java

I have a java program running on Linux machine. 
It invokes an ant target to execute.
I can see the logs on the screen printed but there is no log file, which was produced when i used to run it using shell script.
I want to redirect the screen logs into a file.
I tried "tee" to redirect but it redirects only the part that i am printing in java class.
Can some one help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your build.xml file, you can start and stop recording to a log file:

```
<record name="file.log" action="start"/>
...
<record name="file.log" action="stop"/>
```

See [the appropriate ant documentation](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/recorder.html) for more details.

If you'd rather not edit the build.xml, it is probable that ant is using stderr rather than stdout. Find out what shell you are using and look up how to redirect stdout to stderr. For example, in bash, it would be `ant 2>&1 | tee file.log`.